# How to re save all variations of a variable product when a WooCommerce order is paid?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I use following code to re save the product variations, when there is a paid order on it, but nothing happen

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'refresh_zero_stock');
function refresh_zero_stock($order_id){
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ){
        $item_quantity  = $item->get_quantity();
        if($item_quantity == 0){
            $product_id   = $item->get_product_id();
            $product_data = wc_get_product($product_id);
            if ($product_data->is_type('variable')){
                $handle = new WC_Product_Variable($product_id);
                $variations1=$handle->get_children();
                foreach ($variations1 as $value) {
                    $single_variation=new WC_Product_Variation($value);
                    $single_variation->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

what is the problem with this action hook? please help.

Comment: The main problem is `if($item_quantity == 0){` as  order item quantity is always bigger than 0, so this condition is never `true` so the rest of your code have no effect. You should better try to explain what you are trying to do as there are no details or any context… Why are you using `woocommerce_payment_complete`hook? Why do the order item quantity needs to be `0`? Also try to comment and explain your code please.

Comment: Dear @LoicTheAztec, the problem is, I want to check when an order payed (order status processing) check whether the stock quantity of that product is 0 or not. if it is reduced to 0, then save the variations of that products again. I hop I can stated what I mean. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem. I have to add

```
$variation->set_manage_stock(false);
$variation->set_stock_status('outofstock');
```

before

```
$variation->save();
```

Comment: Nobody could guess and answer that, with the provided code and details from your question…

Comment: If you paid attention to the previous comments, I told you the stock status after the action hook will be change to onbackorder. I do not think there are more details to be said. It depended on your accuracy.

Answer (score 3):

The hook is not the problem… The main problem is `if( $item->get_quantity() == 0 ){` that is always `false`, where `$item->get_quantity()` need to be replaced with the **product stock quantity** instead. Try the following:

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'refresh_zero_stock');
function refresh_zero_stock( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item ){
        $product = $item->get_product(); // Get the current product (object)
        
        // If stock quantity is 0 and if it's a product variation
        if ( $product->get_stock_quantity() == 0 && $product->is_type('variation') ){
            $parent_product = wc_get_product( $item->get_product_id() ); // Get parent variable product
            
                // Loop through children Ids (variations ids) from the parent variable product
                foreach ($parent_product->get_children() as $child_id ) {
                    $variation = wc_get_product( $child_id ); // Get the product variation from each child Id
                    $variation->save(); // refresh and save
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should better works.

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec, I add your codes in functions.php file, and test a product. But nothing happen, the product still show add to cart button for variation. In admin the product status change to onbackorder

Comment: When I manually save the variation in product edit section, add to cart button will be deactivated

Comment: @WebDesign I told you before to give more details and better explain what you are trying to do **in your question**, as there are no details or any context… There is not al related code and explanations in your question, so nobody can really help you.

Comment: I also use this action hook to send SMS to Dokan vendor when seller paid the order without any extra conditions in function, but nothing happened!

Answer (score 3):

As the hook `woocommerce_payment_complete` doesn't seems to work, try the following instead based on order status change *(Note: this code will run only once for each order)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'refresh_zero_stock', 10, 4 );
function refresh_zero_stock( $order_id, $from_status, $to_status, $order ){
    $variations_refreshed = $order->get_meta('_variations_refreshed');

    if( in_array($to_status, array('processing', 'completed') ) && ! $variations_refreshed ) {
        // Loop though order items
        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item ){
            $product = $item->get_product(); // Get the current product (object)

            // If stock quantity is 0 and if it's a product variation
            if ( $product->get_stock_quantity() == 0 && $product->is_type('variation') ){
                $parent_product = wc_get_product( $item->get_product_id() ); // Get parent variable product

                    // Loop through children Ids (variations ids) from the parent variable product
                    foreach ($parent_product->get_children() as $child_id ) {
                        $variation = wc_get_product( $child_id ); // Get the product variation from each child Id
                        $variation->save(); // refresh and save
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Flag the order to make this code run only once for current order
        $order->update_meta_data( '_variations_refreshed', '1' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It could better works.